# Error installing Twisted on Windows 10, Python 3.8.0

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, twisted

Can't install Twisted with `pip install Twisted [windows_platform]` on Windows 10 with Python 3.8.0.
Error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\darkfox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\darkfox\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m3igdq78\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\darkfox\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m3igdq78\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\darkfox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m3igdq78\Twisted\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\darkfox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m3igdq78\Twisted\
    Complete output (83 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\darkfox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
        h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
      File "c:\users\darkfox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1230, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

   //delete fragment

      File "c:\users\darkfox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\darkfox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 766, in open_url
        return open_with_auth(url, self.opener)

      //delete fragment

        raise URLError(err)
    urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\darkfox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m3igdq78\Twisted\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**_setup["getSetupArgs"]())

      //delete fragment

      File "c:\users\darkfox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 779, in open_url
        raise DistutilsError("Download error for %s: %s"
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Download error for https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1d/c98a587dc06e107115cf4a58b49de20b19222c83d75335a192052af4c4b7/incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=717e12246dddf231a349175f48d74d93e2897244939173b01974ab6661406b9f: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

This is a clean installation of windows 10 with just installed python 3.8.0. Python downloaded from official site.

Comment: You seem to be having a connection issue. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I ran into the same Compile issues It allowed me to install Scrapy, which requires Twisted, on my Windows 10 p3.8 work laptop without requiring Admin privileges. Posting this so others might find this solution for Scrapy no admin needed install as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try downloading the `twisted whl` file from [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) link. Download the file with `cp38` in its name.

After downloading the file, open a `cmd` in that folder and run the command:

```
pip install <file.whl>
```

For example, if you downloaded `Twisted‑19.7.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`, use

```
pip install Twisted‑19.7.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: it says "ERROR: Twisted-20.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: what platform are you on? windows? are you using python3.7?

Comment: @Alirezaaraby Look for the .whl links with `cp37` and `win`.