# How to resolve the error of legacy-install-failure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
 building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
      
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": <https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> matplotlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to download [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)  and install it in your system then  select **Workloads** and check the option of **Desktop development using C++** . Once this is complete, you can run the installation command again.

**OR**

You can also choose to download this python library from
 [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib)

1. Download the file with name **pip install matplotlib‑3.5.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl**
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yifZI.png)
2. After downloading the file, open cmd **in that folder** and run the
   command:
3. *pip install matplotlib‑3.5.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl*

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516221/16948192)

Comment: 6 GBs for MSVC (exclude windows11 SDK), is that normal? (haven't done any c++ devs yet)

Answer (score 5):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktecx.png)

You need to download Microsoft C++ Build Tools and install it in your system then select Workloads and check the option of Desktop development using C++ .

pip install -r requirements.txt