# legacy-install-failure when trying to install opencv-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, opencv, pip

I need to install opencv-python version 3.4. When I try to install it I only get a legacy-install-failure.

```
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> opencv-python
```

I tried installing it using

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.0.14
```

I'm using python 3.7 on Ubuntu and I already updated pip, wheel and setuptools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the error of legacy-install-failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451908/how-to-resolve-the-error-of-legacy-install-failure)

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano The OP is on Ubuntu, not w64.

Comment: `opencv-python` 3.4.0.14 [doesn't provide wheels](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.4.0.14/#files) for Python 3.7, at most 3.6. For such an old version either use old Python or [compile from sources](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python#ci-build-process) (which is hard).

Comment: Do you know what Python version I can use?

Comment: @basti07 Did you see the list of wheels?